# std::promise::set_exception with type non extending std::exception calls terminate

Tags: c++, concurrency

In the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    auto ep = std::make_exception_ptr( X ); // (1)
    std::promise<int> p;
    p.set_exception(ep);
    try {
        p.get_future().get();  // (2)
    } catch(const std::exception& exc) {
        std::cout << exc.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if `X` in line (1) is a type not extending `std::exception`, the call at line `(2)` will call terminate. I can't find anywhere this specification.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/K3ErcrYGo) with latest `gcc` and `msvc`

Comment: It calls `std::terminate`, because you are not handling the exception from `p.get_future().get();` anywhere. It would be the same if you replaced it with just `throw X;`. I don't really see why you expect it _not_ to call `std::terminate`. Could you explain your expectations?

Comment: Isn't `p.get_future().get();` wrapped in a `try`/`catch` section?

Comment: Yes, but you are explicitly catching only `std::exception`s.

Comment: And which types of exceptions youy made that catch intercepts?

Comment: Oh yes, I got he point, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, the problem is not catching the right type of exception, e.g. using `catch(...)`.

Comment: fwiw, its not necessarily a "problem". Sometimes, not catching an exception and terminating is just the right thing to do.